# How humidity circulates

Tags: everyday-life, humidity

I was wondering something about humidity circulation. I have observed that, if I left the door of my air conditioned lab slightly open during rainy season the humidity levels increases in the lab rather rapidly.

I can understand that heat is transferred via temperature difference, or air current is generated via pressure difference, however I can not understand why the humidity should be transferred from one place to another.

My question is, If there is no temperature and pressure difference between two parts of a building, whether the humidity can transfer from one place to another. I can only think of diffusion of water molecules but since the mass of water molecule is quite large I think that it is an ineffective means of humidity transfer.

One side question of this is "If I left open the cover of hygroscopic material/desiccant slightly open (such that no air circulation is possible) will it absorb moisture.

thanks in advance,

Comment: The densities of moist air and dry air of the same temperatures differ (dry air is heavier), which will quickly exchange air between indoors and the outside. http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/SimRoof/Convection/density-vs-T.png

Comment: @CuriousOne, Thanks for your comment. I have estimated (from the help of internet) that the difference between density of wet and dry air at 20 deg is ~0.86% (partial pressure of water at 20 degree is~ 25 mbar). With this small number i can not say whether the diffusion of humidity is a density effect or a molecular diffusion effect.

Comment: You can put a candle into the doorway, which should show air movement quite nicely.